# how to clean ie cache between every navigation?

Tags: c#, selenium

I use the following code:

```
string remoteAddress = "";
int timeout = 4;

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
capabilities.SetCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);

IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(remoteAddress), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
```

So when I start ie, it clears cache. I need it to be cleaned between every navigation without closing the browser. Is it possible? If not, I will just keep it that way and restard it. Sometimes it seems to be cleaned between navigations, sometimes not...

I just need to confirm it's possible or not.

Comment: impossible. Closest you have is running something like batch file or powershell script from Java (unrelated to selenium), which is ugly.

Comment: thanks for your answer!! Now I can go working knowing I did the best I could using selenium!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the code above?

```
driver.Manage().DeleteAllCookies();
```

You can delete the cookies and refresh your browser.
Doing this you will get a clean session of your browser.

Comment: from my tests, it doesn't seem to clean the cache... does it for you?

Comment: It works fine for me. PS: I use to run my scripts as administrator.